# Code Signing in Xcode

Tags: macos, xcode4, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I was going to turn on code signing for my mac app so I'm able to submit the app to the mac app store. But when I select the 3rd party mac application cert for code signing it says that there were no profiles matching.

And when I'm trying to build the app like that I'm getting the error:

> Code Sign error: The identity '3rd Party Mac Developer Application'
>   doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default
>   keychain

And I can't figure out why. I've tried to revoke and reinstall my certificate but that doesn't seem to help.

Here's 2 screenshots. Of the code signing part in the build settings and one from keychain access.

[image]

[image]

Maybe your able to see what's wrong?
If you need any more info please let me know! :)

Comment: Did you create the certificate request using the Certificate Assistant in Keychain? Did you do that one the same Mac that you're trying to install this certificate on?

Comment: The private key for the certificate should have a disclosure arrow (little grey arrow pointing either right or down) that should show you the linked certificates. Does it?

Did you do this on the same Mac that you're trying to install the certificates?

Comment: The Certificates was created by going Keychain access > Certificate Assistant > Request certificate from certificate authority and then uploaded to apple so they could generate the certificates for me. And it was done on the same mac as they're installed on.

Comment: Hmm it doesn't seem to have any private keys... What should I do then?

Comment: Please go to iPhone/iPad chat so that I can post images: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/682/iphone-ipad

Comment: I can see my iPhone Developer Certificate there but not my Mac Application certificate. I also tried to drag and drop my Mac application certificate there but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have a missing key. I'm not sure on the reason why it's missing, but creating a new certificate will likely work.

(For other users, this solution was discussed in chat, this answer was posted here as reference.)

Comment: And this is why chat rather than comments is a bad bad bad bad bad idea. I have this issue and can't see the real answer because its buried in hideousness of the SE chat.

Comment: The conversation began here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/682?m=1436278#1436278 so perhaps this will help future followers to see the conversation, unless James wants to update the answer to have more detail.

Answer (score 11):

Go to Build Setting --> Code Signing Identity --> Select Don't Code Sign.
it will not show Build & Error. (This will work only when you don't want to sign in).